# Word for a moment of self-awareness?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for when something happens in life that makes you take a step outside of the normal routine of life and view your self in an existential way.

For example, you witness what the internet calls a "glitch in the matrix" which makes you question reality. Another example would be in the movie: "The Truman Show" when a camera falls out of the sky and he realizes his whole world is a lie.

Example: Ned experienced a moment of _________ making him stop and wonder what the point of all this was.

Comment: I might call this an _epiphany_, but you need to add a sample sentence demonstrating proposed usage. See the SWR tag requirements.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=epiphany

Comment: ***epiphany*** is a somewhat loaded term, which in addition to the "theological" overtones, always implies that the person experiencing it ***gains insight / understanding*** (about life, the universe, and everything). But my guess is when people come up against something "outside normal experience" that disrupts their normal "sense of self", what they *actually* experience is what psychologists  call ***cognitive dissonance*** (they don't gain ***new*** understanding; they actually risk ***losing*** what understanding they thought they already had).

Comment: Are you looking for a word for one's internal processes of questioning existing beliefs about the world, or for a word of the external event that caused those thoughts and feelings?

Comment: @Boondoggle An external event that causes an internal existential crisis.

Comment: **Epiphany** was a favorite of James Joyce.

Answer (score 3):

I will call this an **[eye-opener](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eye-opener)**.

> **Eye-opener** (noun): something that surprises you and teaches you new facts about life, people, etc.

Answer (score 0):

More words (synonyms) besides the two suggested: revelation, insight, realization, inspiration, flash, eureka [moment].

Answer (score 0):

[**Moment of clarity**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moment%20of%20clarity)

> a time when a person suddenly understands something